# Is it possible to trace all the events fired when debugging a Silverlight application in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, intellitrace

I'm debugging a Silverlight application that is consuming 100% CPU usage because some event is being fired repeatedly. First of all, does Intellitrace works on Silverlight?

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy). I used the old free beta version and it did that (if I remember well). It's a great help for UI tuning as well.

Comment: +1 Yeah,  Silverlight spy is a great tool. I'm using 3.0.0.11 it also supports the event viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Intellitrace does not work in Silverlight. If it is truly an event being called over and over you should be able to see it in the call stack if you break into the debugger.

If not, then it's most likely something in the unmanaged portion of the code. You may want to [turn on redraw regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838252.aspx) which can help identify if an element is causing excessive redrawing which can quickly eat the CPU.